# Dependencies between SAS EG and Microsoft Office

Tags: sas

I am currently researching the dependencies between SAS EG v. 9.4 and Microsoft Office.

More specific, if we upgrade from Office 2016 to Office 365, would then the following commands still work in SAS EG as designed:

- libname excel_file.xlsx
- proc export excel_file.xlsx
- ods excel

Also, is the SAS Microsoft Office AddIn relevant for the above mentioned commands? Or does SAS EG need this AddIn to run them?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would think the better place to ask this is SAS communities (communities.sas.com) - this is technically on topic here but you'll get a better answer there.  You need more details though in either place, particularly as to whether you're using EG with a local install of SAS as opposed to using EG to connect to a server - in the latter case none of the stuff matters at all what you have locally installed.

Answer (score 2):

I have used SAS EG with O365 with no issues. O365 just lets you have the most current Office but still installs Office, mostly, like normal. It also provides web services that are very useful.

I have used O365 for years with no issues. SAS Office Add-In surfaces the SAS Integration Technologies in Office and puts a nice UI on them in the ribbon. It is not a dependency for any of the commands you list. It just makes working with SAS, ***from Office***, easier.

SAS Integration Technologies is required for EG so you have that. SAS Access to PC File Formats is also something you have already.

Also, see this if you want to use the Office REST web services:

https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2020/07/09/sas-programming-office-365-onedrive/